# How can I set a struct field value by string name?

Tags: struct, rust

Out of habit from interpreted programming languages, I want to rewrite many values based on their key. I assumed that I would store all the information in the struct prepared for this project. So I started iterating:

```
struct Container {
    x: String,
    y: String,
    z: String
}
impl Container {
    // (...)    
    fn load_data(&self, data: &HashMap<String, String>) {
        let valid_keys = vec_of_strings![ // It's simple vector with Strings
            "x", "y", "z"
        ] ;
        for key_name in &valid_keys {
            if data.contains_key(key_name) {
                self[key_name] = Some(data.get(key_name);
                // It's invalid of course but
                // I do not know how to write it correctly.
                // For example, in PHP I would write it like this:
                // $this[$key_name] = $data[$key_name];
            }
        }
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Maybe macros? I tried to use them. `key_name` is always interpreted as it is, I cannot get value of `key_name` instead.

How can I do this without repeating the code for each value?

Comment: You should first check if your use case isn't simply covered by [`serde`](https://serde.rs/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With macros, I always advocate starting from the direct code, then seeing what duplication there is. In this case, we'd start with

```
fn load_data(&mut self, data: &HashMap<String, String>) {
    if let Some(v) = data.get("x") {
        self.x = v.clone();
    }
    if let Some(v) = data.get("y") {
        self.y = v.clone();
    }
    if let Some(v) = data.get("z") {
        self.z = v.clone();
    }
}
```

Note the number of differences:

1. The struct must take `&mut self`.
2. It's inefficient to check if a value is there and then get it separately.
3. We need to clone the value because we only only have a reference.
4. We cannot store an `Option` in a `String`.

Once you have your code working, you can see how to abstract things. *Always* start by trying to use "lighter" abstractions (functions, traits, etc.). Only after exhausting that, I'd start bringing in macros. Let's start by using `stringify`

```
if let Some(v) = data.get(stringify!(x)) {
    self.x = v.clone();
}
```

Then you can extract out a macro:

```
macro_rules! thing {
    ($this: ident, $data: ident, $($name: ident),+) => {
        $(
            if let Some(v) = $data.get(stringify!($name)) {
                $this.$name = v.clone();
            } 
        )+
    };
}

impl Container {
    fn load_data(&mut self, data: &HashMap<String, String>) {
        thing!(self, data, x, y, z);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = Container::default();
    let d: HashMap<_, _> = vec![("x".into(), "alpha".into())].into_iter().collect(); 

    c.load_data(&d);

    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

---

Full disclosure: I don't think this is a good idea.